# Fixing Orientages of objects in binary images in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, orientation, blob, shapes

I'm running a code to detect the shapes of different objects. Each image contains one object and the code I've created works just fine, provided the images are horizontal. Some images I use though include images that are oriented by some angle to the horizontal. I use the following code to try to fix this:

```
blobMeasurements = regionprops(BW,'Perimeter', 'Area', 'FilledArea', 'Solidity', 'Centroid', 'Orientation')
orientation = [blobMeasurements.Orientation];
BW_rotated = imrotate(BW ,-orientation);
```

This works for some cases, but takes a huge amount of time and processing power for higher-res images. Is there are more effective, faster way to do fix the orientation issue?

Comment: Do you need all the other measurements?  You can probably speed it up by only computing the orientation.

Comment: Agree with Dima.  Just use the `Orientation` parameter.

Comment: Plus, won't the orientation be the same regardless of the image resolution so (within sensible limits) you could just resize/scale down the image first for additional speed.